# В чем разница между 2-мя способами перебора элементов массива (с учетом повторений)?

Tags: javascript

В общем есть массив данных. К примеру: *[0, 3, 3, 5, 2, 1, 0, 4]*

Стояла задача написать функцию, которая принимает этот массив и возвращает объект с **ключом** - *строка* и **значением** - *количество повторений этой строки*.

Два товарища-программиста решили задачу по разному.

> Первый решил следующим образом:

```
const arr = [0, 3, 3, 5, 2, 1, 0, 4]

const func = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc, rec) => Object.assign({}, acc, { [rec]: arr.filter(item => item === rec).length }, {}), 0);

console.log(func(arr)); // { '0': 2, '1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 2, '4': 1, '5': 1 }
```

> Второй решил так:

```
const arr = [0, 3, 3, 5, 2, 1, 0, 4]

const func = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc, rec) => { acc[rec] = !acc[rec] ? 1 : acc[rec] + 1; return acc }, {})

console.log(func(arr)); // { '0': 2, '1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 2, '4': 1, '5': 1 }
```

Вопрос: в чем разница между ними?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первом случае сложность алгоритма *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*, за счет того, что для каждого элемента будет проход по массиву с подсчетом повторений.

Во втором случае сложность алгоритма *O(n)* - то есть все считается за один проход по массиву.

`n` - в обоих случаях это исходное количество элементов.

---

Из этого следует, что для большого `n` первый способ будет работать намного медленнее.

Comment: Тогда ещё один уточняющий вопрос: во втором случае не происходит ли мутация?

Comment: @DENTRE, мутация чего?

Comment: Мутирует объект acc, добавляя в него новые ключи.
acc [rec] = ....

Comment: Разобрался, снизу дам ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно хорошим решением будет "объединить" эти два способа, учитывая ошибки обоих:

> потеря скорости **в первом случае**
>
> мутация объекта "acc" **во втором случае**

Плюс сделаем спредом.

Итог:

```
const arr = [0, 3, 3, 5, 2, 1, 0, 4];

const func = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc, rec) => ({...acc, [rec]: typeof acc[rec] === 'undefined' ? 1 : acc[rec] + 1 }), {});

console.log(func(arr)); // { '0': 2, '1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 2, '4': 1, '5': 1 }
```

Comment: а что плохого в изменении объекта acc? проверка на `undefined` не нужна, потому что ты сам заполняешь этот объект начиная с 1

Comment: ну в этом примере конкретно может и ничего, но в целом мутация = ошибки в коде = малоподдерживаемый код = сидеть на работе 24/7. Иметь привычку писать без мутаций, считаю, правильным решением.